# How use a custom function Twig-symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

We have a Symfony 3.4 project with twig templates and authentication system by FOSUserBundle.

It is multi-domain and manages customer and supplier data mainly works well but now I have a problem that I do not know how to solve at the time of user registration.

I need that depending on the domain, it can show one or another twig template at the time of registration.

Search documentation and find how to write custom twig extension
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/twig_extension.html

This is my function and almost like the one in the example

```php
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('server', [$this, 'serverName']),
        ];
    }

    public function calculateArea(int $width, int $length)
    {
        return $width * $length;
    }

    public function serverName()
    {
        $serverName = "$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]";
        return $serverName;
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I use my function in Twig? I need that based on the domain in which it connects, it showed us a registration form or something like this:

```
{% extends "@FOSUser/layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}

    {% if serverName == "xxxxx"%}
        {% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content_cliente.html.twig" %}
    {% else %}
        {% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content_proveedor.html.twig" %}
    {% endif %}
    
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

It does not work like that:

```
{{ serverName }}
{{ server }}

{% serverName %}
{% server %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as with php you have to call a function using `()`, so <strike>`serverName()`</strike> `server()`, as this is what you call the function in `AppExtension::getFunctions()` (first argument).

You might want to replace that function with a so called [test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#tests). Then you can do something like:

```
{% if 'example.com' is serverName %}
{% endif %}
```

The code could look something like:

```
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getTests()
    {
        return [
            new TwigTest('serverName', [$this, 'isServerName']),
        ];
    }

    public function isServerName(string $serverName)
    {
        return $serverName === $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME];
    }
}
```

Alternatively in your templates you always have access to the request with the variable `app.request` which you can ask for the current server name using one of the methods on Symfony's Request object. For example you can use `Request::getHost()` for the comparison:

```
{% if app.request.host == 'example.com' %}
{% endif %}
```

No function or test or other twig extension necessary.

Comment: Thank you, i found the solution with the follow doc  https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/app_variable.html,